# Find indices of unique array in a non-unique array with non-numeric items

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory

I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c','a','a','d','e'])
b = np.array(['a','b'])
```

actual data stored  in the arrays are uuids, example:

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000
```

I would like to search b in a and get the indices:

```
array([0, 3, 4, 1])
```

this solution can work for me:

```
np.nonzero(b[:, None] == a)[1]
```

but the problem is I'm dealing with huge arrays (15M in the non-unique and 150k in the unique sub-array with str_ type), so for the given operation I would need 1.8TB of memory which I don't have.

any idea how can I solve this issue or workaround the memory restrictions with my own solution?

thanks.

Comment: Would they be all one character strings?

Comment: no actually its more like long unique identifier: "abd2-ffb3-ffv3-dda1" (something like this)

Comment: So, are all strings of the same length?

Comment: yes they are of the same length. Its a uuid

Comment: Also, do you need output in that specific order of `array([0, 3, 4, 1])` or would a sorted order `array([0, 1, 3, 4])` be okay?

Comment: any order is fine, I  just need the indices to retrieve relevant values from the arrays that has the data.

Comment: In that case `np.flatnonzero(np.isin(a,b))` should do?

Comment: as a side question, wouldn't using the UUIDs as 128-bit numbers, rather than strings, make things easier?

Comment: @yatu that actually did the trick!! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the order of the indices isn't really relevant, you can use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), and then [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) on the results to retrieve the indices where the returned array is `True`:

```
a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c','a','a','d','e'])
b = np.array(['a','b'])

np.flatnonzero(np.isin(a,b))
# array([0, 1, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

This should be reasonably fast and memory efficient (`O(len(a))`) unlike the broadcasting approach (`O(len(a)*len(b))`), even with the array sizes mentioned in the question:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,15e2,int(15e6))
b = np.random.randint(0,150e3,int(150e3))

%timeit np.flatnonzero(np.isin(a,b))
# 2.58 s ± 28.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one based on `view`+`lookup` -

```
def map_indices_conststring(a, b):
    a2D = a.view(np.uint8)[::4].reshape(len(a),-1)
    b2D = b.view(np.uint8)[::4].reshape(len(b),-1)
    
    n = b2D.shape[1]
    lookup = np.zeros(256, dtype=bool)
    mask = np.ones(len(a), dtype=bool)
    for i in range(n):
        lookup[b2D[:,i]] = 1
        mask &= lookup[a2D[:,i]]
    out = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [46]: a
Out[46]: 
array(['a123', 'b232', 'c434', 'b235', 'a123', 'd223', 'b232'],
      dtype='<U4')

In [47]: b
Out[47]: array(['a123', 'b232'], dtype='<U4')

In [48]: map_indices_conststring(a, b)
Out[48]: array([0, 1, 4, 6])
```

Timings on string data with `1.5M` non-unique and `15K` unique sized string arrays -

```
In [2]: a = np.random.randint(10000000000,99999999999,(1500000)).astype(str)

In [3]: b = np.unique(np.random.randint(10000000000,99999999999,(15000)).astype(str))

In [4]: %timeit map_indices_conststring(a, b)
266 ms ± 2.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# @yatu's soln
In [5]: %timeit np.flatnonzero(np.isin(a,b))
1.03 s ± 3.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```